# Recursive / Loop Finishing top layer before go into lower layer

Tags: loops, recursion

I have a problem with this recursive loop.

Imagine that there are messages and I need to forward them. There are three people total: H, S and A. The forwarding pattern goes like this.

Imgine if someone send H a message and because H never received this message, he is going to forward to S and A. When S receives the message, it is the first time that S receives the message so he is going to send to H and A.

H
        /   \
     S      A

    / \      / \
  H  A   S  H

My problem is in my approach, it would go something like H->S->H->A->S
because my approach is somewhat recursive-like.

Can someone provide me an algorithm so that I can go  H->S and H->A before going one layer under(S-> H and S->A) ?

Thanks.

Comment: What you're looking for is called a "breadth first search".

Answer (score 0):

The first thought that comes to my mind is for you to queue up the values in the order that you want to visit them.  For example.

```
Start at H, queue up S and A.

Next in line is S, queue up H and A.
Next in line is A, queue up S and H.

Next in line is H, nothing to queue.
Next in line is A, nothing to queue.
Next in line is S, nothing to queue.
Next in line is H, nothing to queue.

Nothing left in line.
```

Something like that.